# How to send alerts based on Kubernetes / Docker events?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to somehow send alerts (to email / slack) based on events that occur within a Kubernetes cluster?

In particular, it would be useful to get an alert if a pod has restarted unexpectedly or if a pod cannot start. Similarly it would be useful to know if a pod's CPU usage was over a certain threshold and get an alert.

We have Heapster (with InfluxDB / Grafana backend) installed. While this gives useful data, it unfortunately does not provide us with alerting.

Answer (score 3):

Both [sysdig](http://thenewstack.io/sysdig-adds-kubernetes-container-monitoring-cloud/) and [Datadog](http://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/kubernetes/) provide this functionality as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can check and probably replace InfluxDB with http://prometheus.io (I am not sure about your cases but generally it is possible) which has built-in metrics support.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for each issue you mentioned is a little different. Lets look at them one at a time.

### Pod restarts and related issues:

[I wrote an open source tool named Robusta to do this.](https://github.com/robusta-dev/robusta)

First a screenshot, then an explanation:

[image: pod restarts]

This works by listening to events from the APIServer and running a builtin automation when pods are in `CrashLoopBackOff` state. By default, it fetches logs and sends them to Slack, but that's configurable.

The configuration follows, but keep in mind that you don't need to actually configure this. It's included in the default configuration file:

```yaml
- triggers:
  - on_pod_update: {}
  actions:
  - restart_loop_reporter:
      restart_reason: CrashLoopBackOff
  - image_pull_backoff_reporter:
      rate_limit: 3600
```

### High CPU

You should do this with Prometheus.

You can route Prometheus through Robusta if you want to gather extra information. For example, you can run a bash command to gather extra information from the pod which is firing the alert. Or you can send a graph of the relevant metric.